# Infer types in tuple's arrays

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples, type-inference

Consider, I have a structure, like:

```
type X = { args: readonly any[]; fn: (...args: any[]) => void }[]
```

I would like to infer `X[number]['args']` in `X[number]['fn']`, for example:

```
[{ args: [1,2,3] as const, fn: (a, b, c) => {} }] // a should be 1, b=2, c=3
```

In order to do that I create helper function, which should keep constraints

```
type Arguments<Args> = Args extends any[] ? Args : Args extends readonly any[] ? Args : [];

type InferProviders<Providers> = {
  // Providers[Property] is actually `unknown`. Why?
  [Property in keyof Providers]: Providers[Property] extends { args: infer Args } ? { args: Args, fn: (...args: Arguments<Args>) => any } : never
};

function fn<Providers>(providers: InferProviders<Providers>) {
  return providers;
}
```

But when I use this function I don't get expected result:

```
const x = fn([
  { args: [1,2,3], fn: (a, b, c) => {} }, // expected `a` to be 1, b = 2, c = 3
  { args: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], fn: (a, b, c) => {} }, // a = 'foo', b = 'bar', c = 'baz'
  { args: ['x', 'y', 'z'], fn: (e, b, c) => {} }, // e = 'x', b ='y',  c = 'z'
] as const); 
// typeof x is [never, never, never]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwK4FsIDtgGcA88FYB8UAvLIllBAB7AYAmlAhuiANoC6UA-OQVAC4%20lGnXSMocCE3oB7dABsQUFuy698lIZwDcAKD2hIUAJLoAZhDgAFOLIBuAS3pXcth89fEyAbz1QoAHpAqHcnFzgsNndIOFAuR2YAY2AkJgUlKAADJHQAa3RZAHd0LIA6KAB1AAsQbn8oaLtY0ChHdCg8iBBZc1C7cNcOITDPSKbZFpAuUQZKHxUKIXbLOGEoAF8eKAWmJeEAGihzdCEACjLLvYIhfFQMbDwKQgBKUmJVTcEodAh7Kz0G30enMuRSjnkx3QOFGESIZzAAzGWCEZlWsNcMKRcNeOwaUlScA6iI8cP0GwMSXkWGAUBJg0ipEa-l2%20zYAEYDgAmA4AZg4RxO5yYRwARkckm8SMQfFsNgcWYsbo0AOTmWSyFVHFWivZaqA6pgALxVAqhwrFEqlMrlCp2SpRquo%20pVIBdJrNQqgZwglqgkveOzlei4TEoVPQNP0Rmg1iZMd6dOxrn0wSgACEkLTqlZoCYoAgILSqXApCkoDHDOBY2syGirBjIjDCMCIzSoNQmSczmwGqzlRzuXzPadvSKoOL-dag5sjmmaJAUhB6NkmFkK7IJ9BOROmTz-UzeX2Hdo1RqXbq4BfjabBaOzuPJwHpTP5UEQkwmWfNWKv5f9Ukf43se1yOmwKrOtqbrah6d7nL6E5WoGsqzu%20VBfpBu4kK6%20oHmQKomiGKjhtSwAvDoQA)

Could anyone help how to infer types correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The TypeScript compiler is not really good at inferring both [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters and the [contextual type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of callback parameters at the same time, if one depends on the other, especially in a single function parameter.  This is a design limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) for a similar issue, and especially [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872#issuecomment-651450956) which explains what's going on.

The best I could imagine doing for your `fn()` as written would be to rewrite the typings like this:

```
type InferProviders<T> = { [K in keyof T]: 
  { args: T[K], fn: (...args: Extract<T[K], readonly any[]>) => any } 
};

function fn<P extends readonly (readonly any[])[]>(
  providers: InferProviders<P>) {
  return providers;
}
```

And you will see that it compiles with no error and actually produces a value of the right type:

```
const x = fn([
  { args: [1, 2, 3], fn: (a, b, c) => { } }, 
  { args: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], fn: (a, b, c) => { } }, 
  { args: ['x', 'y', 'z'], fn: (e, b, c) => { } }, 
] as const); // okay


/* const x: readonly [{
    args: readonly [1, 2, 3];
    fn: (args_0: 1, args_1: 2, args_2: 3) => any;
}, {
    args: readonly ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    fn: (args_0: "foo", args_1: "bar", args_2: "baz") => any;
}, {
    args: readonly ["x", "y", "z"];
    fn: (args_0: "x", args_1: "y", args_2: "z") => any;
}] */
```

But unfortunately, the contextual type inference for the callback parameters happens too late for them to be useful inside the callback implementations themselves:

```
const x = fn([
  { args: [1, 2, 3], fn: (a, b, c) => { a.oops } }, // a, b, c are any
  { args: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], fn: (a, b, c) => { b.oops } }, // a, b, c are any
  { args: ['x', 'y', 'z'], fn: (e, b, c) => { c.oops } }, // e, b, c are any
] as const);
```

If you're willing to annotate the types of your callback parameters (thereby obviating the need for contextual type inference), then that's fine:

```
const y = fn([
  { args: [1, 2, 3], 
    fn: (a: 1, b: 2, c: 3) => { a.oops } }, // error!
  { args: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 
    fn: (a: "foo", b: "bar", c: "baz") => { b.toUpperCase() } }, // okay
  { args: ['x', 'y', 'z'], 
    fn: (e: "x", b: "y", c: "z") => { c.toLowerCase() } }, // okay
] as const); // okay
```

---

But if you really want contextual type inference, there's not much I can do here, unfortunately, without refactoring the way you call `fn()`.  For example, you could require that someone create providers using a dedicated function where you use separate parameters for `args` and for `fn`, so that the compiler has an easier time with inference:

```
function provider<T extends readonly any[]>(args: T, fn: (...args: T) => any) {
  return { args, fn };
}
```

and then your call to `fn()` would be:

```
const z = fn([
  provider([1, 2, 3] as const, (a, b, c) => a.toFixed()),
  provider(["foo", "bar", "baz"] as const, (a, b, c) => b.toLowerCase()),
  provider([1, 2, 3] as const, (a, b, c) => a.toFixed()),
] as const)
```

which works, but is somewhat unfortunate.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwgJwArIPYDcCWATFAZwB4AVKCAD2Ajj0KmQgEM8M4AbEKACidfZcozOCADaAXQCUkgHxQAvACgoUAN5QxAaSg44UANYQQGBFFISAXOuHIA5oWultEgDRQEcazwB0f5vaOUACi1MjMAMbAZC7u-Gyc3CLiErJSivLJUAC+OUpKCACucFE47B5wxKgU1LT0jCwJQnyNgkmikjKpPCpQYJi4BMhB8EhoA-hEVWnqvUzAhcj6-diTwwDcStn5EeyEwFCUihU8Yr0aAQ7WYgCM7gBM7gDMbhXezO4ARu4R6QryFx8GAwYAYuWy7gA9JDhF8frZoMlzrYrpoAOQIYFo9xoz4BbFQXHMABeaNennecKgvwyNk+QJBYJyUJhHyg32pCOEomRlyCYjRlAJaJAwtJ5K8vAgVJp-xsEQZoJyzKg0IoMq5SIkwgYuzg+yk61VMIwBmYIHykIAVNS9gdKNZ4m1NGpeqo+Y7WolNHcoI8oC9NqpVBTeHyAPoABmsvojN2s-oj92sTz+mVEmwhs2DKKCTu9YgARJiMIX3IW8cgy1AKyTCxIg8HQzwI9GayXq3HrLWq+4k928cTC2nuSBM+5XTmPQ0BAXC5Rq4WQIuhw23W8w4Eo92F32t-Ga8u9w5w8ma0OR8lM9qrZD8js7VBuAoTmdVBdAtdff6Xu5m8wYy+BMfhTEdAWBJVwRZChkEwZAAEJeU-dES2FSs0JJMk-0lFtuw7ICa0rasIgHOswPZHxgAwABVMBIGQABhZhCAgHh0ig40oFNc0kNRAUhRxUUcXFbDvAgHdq0+bsj2pbsL1pDQFSogAZDAAHcUCYli2OVLM1W4i1tWY219WAQ1OIM-IihKYAymWCYhjIGoaDoBh8yEZI5BbZDSFE3g-B8adSEvUR0knBoFiWGw+WwnJMwfUyoGJY5PFOXoVkGFBTm-Z4jN1O13BbGVL0ojAADEcEoCA8DYqRXHShysqLfDCICRdB3rHUTP2Qq2Q5WV5HpFT1M05jWKkOqGtWIZsoeXKur1Hqw2K2lmFKiqqpqib6ry7qzKAA)